# How to limit pdf.js to render limited number pages of a pdf file?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, pdf, pdf.js

I have a directory on my server that contains pdf files.
I want to give the option of viewing the pdf files to my users based on their account type, i.e.: basic users can only see 10 pages of pdf files and premium accounts can view the full content of pdf files.
I need to know how to limit the pdf.js to render only a limited number of pdf files.

Searching the pdf.js GitHub repository I found this example
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/prevnext.html 
 and tried to use it in my application as below:
As you can see I am passing the pdf path through a variable called *$file_path* and the maximum number of pages with *$maximumPage* variable.

```
@extends('master')
@section('head')
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Previous/Next example</title>
@stop
@section('content')
<h1>'Previous/Next' example</h1>

<div>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
&nbsp; &nbsp;
<span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span> 
</div>

<div>
<canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
</div>

<!-- For legacy browsers add compatibility.js -->
<!--<script src="../compatibility.js"></script>-->

<script src="{{asset('js/pdfjs/src/pdf.js')}}"></script>

<script id="script">
//
// If an absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
// header on that server.
//
//
 var url = '{{asset($file_path)}}';

//
// Disable workers to avoid yet another cross-origin issue (workers need
// the URL of the script to be loaded, and dynamically loading a cross-origin
// script does not work).
//
// PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

//
// In cases when the pdf.worker.js is located in a different folder than the
// pdf.js's one, or the pdf.js is executed via eval(), the workerSrc property
// shall be specified.
//
// PDFJS.workerSrc = '../../build/pdf.worker.js';

var pdfDoc = null,
        pageNum = 1,
        pageRendering = false,
        pageNumPending = null,
        scale = 0.8,
        canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/**
 * Get page info from the document, resize canvas accordingly, and render the page.
 * @param num Page number.
 */
function renderPage(num) {
    pageRendering = true;
    // Using promise to fetch the page
    pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

        // Wait for rendering to finish
        renderTask.promise.then(function () {
            pageRendering = false;
            if (pageNumPending !== null) {
                // New page rendering is pending
                renderPage(pageNumPending);
                pageNumPending = null;
            }
        });
    });

    // Update page counters
    document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
}

/**
 * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
 * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
 */
function queueRenderPage(num) {
    if (pageRendering) {
        pageNumPending = num;
    } else {
        renderPage(num);
    }
}

/**
 * Displays previous page.
 */
function onPrevPage() {
    if (pageNum <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    pageNum--;
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

/**
 * Displays next page.
 */
function onNextPage() {
    if (pageNum >= {{$maximumPages}}) {
        return;
    }
    pageNum++;
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

/**
 * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
 */
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

    // Initial/first page rendering
    renderPage(pageNum);
});
</script>
@stop
```

The problem is that it doesn't display the pdf although the path gets filled correctly.
I should mention that I am using the Laravel framework and I am new to it so I put the pdf file into the public directory of my Laravel application.

Here is the page source and the value that the URL gets once I run my application:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/pdf/books/Database Systems - Design, Implementation, and Management (9th Edition).pdf';
```

I am really confused what could go wrong that I can't view the PDF file.

Any help would be appreciated.

I finally figured out what was the problem I just needed to uncomment the path for PDFJS.workerSrc as my application couldn't find the path correctly.
After uncommenting the following line

```
// PDFJS.workerSrc = '../../build/pdf.worker.js';
```

to

```
    PDFJS.workerSrc = '{{ asset('js/build/pdf.worker.js') }}';
```

I can now see my PDF file on the web page.

Comment: try to this https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

Comment: @RohitAzad I already looked through github but I couldn't find my answer. Maybe you can help me with some code snippets